# Can I set up Gnome to pop-up its main menu anywhere when I right-click on desktop, and apps (windows) list on middle-click?

Tags: gnome, menu, taskbar

In XFCE it was very convenient to pop-up applications launcher menu and running applications list menu anywhere on desktop by right and middle click respectively. Can be Gnome configured to behave so?

I never put any files/folders on desktop, so I don't need desktop context menu functionality. I also have a very big second monitor and am pretty disturbed by moving mouse over it to the first screen to use taskbar (and placing taskbar on that second big screen wont help much, as it is still big).

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the menu from the panel and hit Alt + F1 the menu will appear at the mouse cursor.  If you use Compiz you can then use the commands plugin along with [xte](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) to simulate keyboard presses and make Alt + F1 be any mouse/corner press you want.

xte is part of the xautomation package:  sudo apt-get install xautomation

This is a helpful tutorial on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=875262).

There is also [MyGTKmenu](http://sites.google.com/site/jvinla/mygtkmenu), which allows you to easily create your own custom menu.

Then there's [apwal](http://apwal.free.fr/), which allows you to create a custom application-launcher-thing (something like an "application wall", get it?) which can be assigned to open with mouse buttons.  It's available in the repos.

Then don't forget about [GNOME Do](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Main_Page) and [Kupfer](http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/), which in my opinion are far superior to any menu.

Oh, and don't forget about the mouse gesture program [Easystroke](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easystroke/), which allows you to run any keyboard command, script etc., with simple mouse movements rather than having to click your desktop at all.  For example, I can open my main menu by holding the middle mouse button and moving the mouse up.  Takes less than a second and it doesn't matter what window the pointer is in.  It's available in the repositories.